# Text Gradient Highcharts Wordcloud

Tags: highcharts, word-cloud

Wordcloud-highcharts is now available in its latest release (>=6.0) and now I am baffling with laying out the gradient (linear/radial) over texts. For example in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/wordcloud-rotation), if I change the colors array in the series object to

```
    fillColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 200],
      stops: [
        [0, 'white'],
        [1, 'black']
      ]
    },
```

It does nothing.

Wordcloud has limited functionality and however I am unable to do accomplish this task. Even tried appending multiple defs for different text gradients with (*k is such that, it lies between 0 to n*)

```
    <defs>
<radialGradient id="myRadialGradient_k"
   fx="5%" fy="5%" r="65%"
   spreadMethod="pad">
  <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#00ee00" stop-opacity="1"/>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#006600" stop-opacity="1" />
</radialGradient>
</defs>
```

and searching for the class and apply css to fill with this *myLinearGradient_k* by `fill:url(#myLinearGradient_k);`. But it is very clumsy and heavy. Also search by id is not possible in this case and appending to class highcharts-point is the only possibility, which limits the options.

Comment: Just so I'm not misunderstanding, what do you want this gradient for? Based on X-axis position? Based on weight? Just the same gradient across all texts?

Comment: Gradient based on weight. e.g. if the relv weigt is 4/10, then it's stop points accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this **live demo** helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mnj07vam/

In `chart.events.load` I placed the code responsible for finding maximum weight, creating gradients (every point has a separate one) and applying them:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var points = this.series[0].points,
          renderer = this.renderer,
          maxWeight = 0;

        // find maximum weight   
        points.forEach(function(p) {
          if (p.weight > maxWeight) {
            maxWeight = p.weight;
          }
        });


        points.forEach(function(p, i) {
          var id = 'grad' + i;


          // create gradient
          var gradient = renderer.createElement('linearGradient').add(renderer.defs).attr({
            id: id,
            x1: "0%",
            y1: "0%",
            x2: "100%",
            y2: "0%"
          });

          var stop1 = renderer.createElement('stop').add(gradient).attr({
            offset: "0%",
            style: "stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"
          });

          var stop2 = renderer.createElement('stop').add(gradient).attr({
            offset: Math.round(p.weight / maxWeight * 100) + "%",
            style: "stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"
          });

          // apply gradient
          p.update({
            color: 'url(#' + id + ')'
          }, false);

        });
        this.redraw();
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#createElement

Comment: So, calling everything on load is a way, thanks for the response.